# Getting count of users sign-in, in AWS Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint, multiple-users

I want how many users are signing in , signing out on my company webpage in aws pinpoint analytics dashboard. Basically I want the count.

I tried many documentations on aws and on other websites but not getitng the expected results required to solve my problem statement.